# How to filter nested array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I need to filter array of objects with the existing filter, for example

```
const students= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Alan",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "math",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "poetry",
                mark: 4
            },
            {
                name: "physics",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Joe",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "geography",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "music",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "literature",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Megan",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "math",
                mark: 4
            },
            {
                name: "physics",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

```
const filters = [
  {
    name: "math",
    mark: 5
  },
  {
    name: "physics",
    mark: 3
  }
];
```

From **students** array I need to get **Alan** and **Megan** according to existing **filters**. So if at least one subject from filters with mark exists in students, I need to get that student.

I tried this

```
const common: any = students.filter((x: any) => {
      return filters.indexOf(x.skills) !== -1;
    });
     console.log(common);
```

But the common array is empty so it didn't work

Comment: what is your expected output? An array of student names?

Comment: Because your objects are a mix between array and object, I've a question. Is the students order has always "math" at first if they have "math".  Alan and Megan have math in first position. Joe doesn't have math. Let say with have another student John with math: math in first position or could be anywhere?

Comment: Math could be anywhere in subjects array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter` and `Array#some` methods as follows:

```js
const 
    students = [ { id: 1, name: "Alan", subjects: [ { name: "math", mark: 5 }, { name: "poetry", mark: 4 }, { name: "physics", mark: 3 } ] }, { id: 2, name: "Joe", subjects: [ { name: "geography", mark: 5 }, { name: "music", mark: 5 }, { name: "literature", mark: 3 } ] }, { id: 3, name: "Megan", subjects: [ { name: "math", mark: 4 }, { name: "physics", mark: 3 } ] } ],
    filters = [ { name: "math", mark: 5 }, { name: "physics", mark: 3 } ],
    
    output = students.filter(
        ({subjects}) => filters.some(
            ({name,mark}) => subjects.some(
                ({name:n,mark:m}) => n === name && m === mark
            )
        )
    );
    
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const students= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Alan",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "math",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "poetry",
                mark: 4
            },
            {
                name: "physics",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Joe",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "geography",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "music",
                mark: 5
            },
            {
                name: "literature",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Megan",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "math",
                mark: 4
            },
            {
                name: "physics",
                mark: 3
            }
        ]
    }
];

  const filters = [
    {
      name: "math",
      mark: 5
    },
    {
      name: "physics",
      mark: 3
    }
  ];


const results = [];

for (const student of students) {
  for (const subject of student.subjects) {
    const check = filters.some(filter => {
      return filter.name == subject.name && filter.mark == subject.mark;
    });
    if (check) results.push({name: student.name,subject: subject.name,mark: subject.mark});
  }
}

console.log(results);

// Output:
// [
//   {
//     "name": "Alan",
//     "subject": "math",
//     "mark": 5
//   },
//   {
//     "name": "Alan",
//     "subject": "physics",
//     "mark": 3
//   },
//   {
//     "name": "Megan",
//     "subject": "physics",
//     "mark": 3
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One (*kind of silly, but*) simple way is to apply a `filter()` to the array and then `stringify` the **subjects** and **filters** for comparison. Because two identical (*but separate*) objects will never evaluate to equal each other, we can't just compare the object. One common alternative is to loop through each of the objects properties for comparison, but in this specific case it's not needed.

```js
const students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Alan",
    subjects: [
      { name: "math", mark: 5 },
      { name: "poetry", mark: 4 },
      { name: "physics", mark: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Joe",
    subjects: [
      { name: "geography", mark: 5 },
      { name: "music", mark: 5 },
      { name: "literature", mark: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Megan",
    subjects: [
      { name: "math", mark: 4 },
      { name: "physics", mark: 3 }
    ]
  }
],
filters = [
  { name: "math", mark: 5 },
  { name: "physics", mark: 3 }
]

let common = students.filter(s => {
  let keep = false
  filters.forEach(f => {
    if(JSON.stringify(s.subjects).includes(JSON.stringify(f))) keep = true
  })
  return keep
})

console.log(common)
```

Is this the best way to do this, probably not. However, given what OP has asked for, this does work and is an interesting way to simplify comparing objects.

Comment: Thank you for unusual approach to solve this problem.